# Listen to HTTP requests

Tags: c#, http, webserver

I have a C# form application which I want to have listening for incoming HTTP requests from other computers.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Egil, please tag with the technology you are using, it would avoid people guessing the framework. Of course you can use ASP .NET if you already have the web server part, which in general means running under IIS, but I suspect this is not the case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For simple needs, the [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) class is a good and simple choice. There is an example on the linked MSDN page.

If, for some reason, you cannot use `HttpListener`, the process would be to listen to a port using `TcpClient` (or even the sockets API if you need the gritty details), and then implement the [HTTP Protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). I highly recommend `HttpListener` over rolling your own, unless you have specific requirements that `HttpListener` does not meet.

Comment: Will this let me listen to requests from other computers too (e.g. my browser on my phone)?

Comment: Yes, `HttpListener` in essence turns your app into a mini HTTP server.

Comment: If you don't use HttpListener, and don't want the lower-level TcpClient approach, have a look at http://www.fiddler2.com/core/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET Http Filters to intercept HTTP requests.
See more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx)

Comment: I would guess, if he is asking how to listen to incoming requests, that this is not anything ASP .NET.

Comment: @Egil No this wouldn't - you could use ASP.Net to handle HTTP requests (i.e. produce the response document), but you still need the part that understands the HTTP protocol (i.e. the web server).

Comment: No ... In that way, you will need a basic ASP.NET application with an Http Filter.

Comment: @driis, but it works if he wants to process/intercept/handle http requests.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an asp.net application, you can check the http requests in the Application_BeginRequest event handler of your global.asax.