# WPF receive GET request's query string sent to localhost socket

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

How do I capture a GET request query string sent to my localhost?

```
http://localhost:4567/?data=VALUE&some=more
```

I have a WPF app which sends a GET request to an Auth website and that website redirects it to localhost on port 4567 with ?data=VALUE in query, and the VALUE is the auth token I need to use in my WPF app to proceed.

How can I get get the VALUE? Do I need to set up a socket listener or there's an easier way? I need only the VALUE, nothing else.

Comment: I know how to do that with a web app or web api, but never did it with a desktop application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739946/listen-to-http-requests