# How to add Web API to existing Windows Service

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi, worker-service

is there any way to add Web API to existing Windows Service application ?
Like adding new port on which to listen for http requests.

Currently service start point is looking like this:

```
ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new WinService1() };   
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

Using .net 6.

I know there is also worker service provided by .net core if the former is not possible can i migrate existing project to worker service and then add Web API ?
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: so your new web api is "core" or "framework" ? because as far as I know you can't mix them

Comment: @Nitz web api is core (.net 6),existing Windows Service application is also on .net 6 there is no mixing. However I figured out how to do it. Will post answer later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. So this is the steps:

##### 1. In project .csproj file Changed target project SDK

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`  to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web>`

##### 2. Changed base class of service

`WinService1: ServiceBase` to `WinService1: BackgroundService`

##### 3. Changed application entry point like this

using this example: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/windows-service/samples/6.x/WebAppServiceSample

```
ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new WinService1() };   
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

to

```
var options = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<WinService1>();

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapRazorPages();
await app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have your answer at anothoer SO post.
[Listen to HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739946/listen-to-http-requests)

You will have to think about threading and authentication depending on your usecase.

More from microsoft at
[HTTP Listner documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-6.0)